# Why can't my Source Generator project load System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2022 17.3.6. I have a Source Generator project that is .NET Standard 2.0 as required.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsRoslynComponent>true</IsRoslynComponent>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="4.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="6.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As you can see I added PackageReference to System.Text.Json 6.0.6.
I also added a debug profile for trobleshooting. The following is Properties\launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Profile 1": {
      "commandName": "DebugRoslynComponent",
      "targetProject": "..\\Enigma.GameWPF\\Enigma.GameWPF.csproj"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run debug by clicking the play button in visual studio, I got following error

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Edit 3 Nov 2022**

I just found how to fix it, but it is very weird.
The source generator is like this

```
    [Generator]
    public class SourceGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator {
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context) {
            Generate(context);
        }

        public static void Generate(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context) {
            var names = context.AdditionalTextsProvider
                .Where(static at => at.Path.EndsWith("JsonFile.json"))
                .SelectMany(static (at, _) => {
                    JsonDocument jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(at.GetText(_).ToString());
                    return jsonDocument.RootElement.EnumerateArray();
                })
                .Select(static (je, _) => je.GetProperty("GeneratedClassName").GetString());

            context.RegisterSourceOutput(names, static (context, name) => {
                string sourceCode = $@"
public class {name}{{
}}
";
                context.AddSource(name + ".g.cs", sourceCode);
            });
        }
    }
```

By the code above, error will occur. However, just inline the Generate method can fix it:

```
    [Generator]
    public class SourceGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator {
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context) {
            var names = context.AdditionalTextsProvider
                .Where(static at => at.Path.EndsWith("JsonFile.json"))
                .SelectMany(static (at, _) => {
                    JsonDocument jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(at.GetText(_).ToString());
                    return jsonDocument.RootElement.EnumerateArray();
                })
                .Select(static (je, _) => je.GetProperty("GeneratedClassName").GetString());

            context.RegisterSourceOutput(names, static (context, name) => {
                string sourceCode = $@"
public class {name}{{
}}
";
                context.AddSource(name + ".g.cs", sourceCode);
            });
        }
    }
```

I made a demo and uploaded it to Onedrive, please take a look for more detail.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkUvAiWJaUWkiqURrwKERel90zqERQ?e=1IYhq6

Comment: Check the "System.Text.Json" version and path referenced in each project in the solution one by one, make sure that the "System.Text.Json.dll" file referenced by each application set is in the same path.

Comment: @Lynn-MSFT I just added some detail, please have a look

Comment: I have aother project in the solution that is .NET 6 and used System.Text.Json. But that is included in .NET6 without need to reference anything

Comment: Hi,@martinrhan. Have you solved all your problems? What is your specific problem with another .NET 6 project?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT Yes I have solved it, see https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/47517
https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/7640